# Two inner joins of table columns to a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I am developing a loans system, in which upon loan maturity money plus interest is moved from borrower's account to the lender. However, this can only happen if the borrower has enough money to do so, otherwise nothing happens so far.

I have one table with the different users and their cash.

```
USERS

+--id--+--name--+--group--+--cash-+
```

And another one with the details of every loan.

```
LOANS

+--LoanId--+--Lender--+--lenderId--+--Borrower--+--borrowerId--+--principal--+--rate--+--term-+--due_date--+
```

My code for deducting money from borrower (if the borrower has enough money) is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users AS u
        INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l.borrowerId, SUM(l.principal + ((l.principal*l.rate*l.term)/1200)) AS total_due
    FROM loans AS l
    WHERE l.due_date = '2019-03-24'
    GROUP BY l.borrowerId
                    ) AS d
        ON d.borrowerId = u.id
        SET u.cash = CASE WHEN u.cash > d.total_due THEN u.cash - d.total_due ELSE u.cash END";
```

And it works just fine, but when I try to both deduct form borrower and add money to lender I find trouble with u.cash > d.total_due since it could be making reference to both lender and borrower.

I have tried this, but it would not work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users AS u
        INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l.lenderId, SUM(l.principal + ((l.principal*l.rate*l.term)/1200)) AS total_due
    FROM loans AS l
    WHERE l.due_date = '2019-03-24'
    GROUP BY l.lenderId
                    ) AS d
        ON d.lenderId = u.id

        INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l.borrowerId
    FROM loans AS l
    WHERE l.LoanId = d.LoanId
    GROUP BY l.lenderId
    ON d.borrowerId = u.id
                   ) AS b

        SET u.cash = CASE WHEN b.cash > d.total_due THEN u.cash + d.total_due ELSE u.cash END";
```

I would deeply appreciate your kind help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you aggregate multiple loans for user's cash update? It would be easier to update debits/credits by `loan_id` each time loan is procured.

Comment: You are making things complicated with mysql doing the logic. You could use php script to do the logic and update your database thereafter.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I agree with @McBern, you could also make your life (and code readability) easier by doing two `UPDATE` queries within a transaction that can be rolled back if the query fails or another exception occurs. Trying to jam everything into the one query is acceptable, but hard to maintain sometimes -- and in my own experience, often less performant than running separate queries.

Comment: This appears to be what transactions were invented for

Comment: @Jeremy_Harris, Parfait and Mcbern the reason I'm doing what I'm doing is because 1) the queries cannot be triggered onclick but on a certain date and 2) both lenders and borrowers have the same condition of users and are recorded in the same table as they act continously as borrowers and lenders at the same time (that is why the u.cash reference gives me the hard time). How would you suggest to proceed considering this?